# Python selenium firefox browser launch error

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am trying to launch Firefox (48.0.2) using Selenium with Python 3.5 on my mac using the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://bbc.co.uk')
```

However, Firefox launches without going to the specified webpage and times out with the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anthonyperera/Documents/Python/AutomatePython/seleniumexample.py", line 2, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 68, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 108, in _wait_until_connectable
    % (self.profile.path))
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: /var/folders/6n/_xgjldp12r59c6gdvgb46nsm0000gn/T/tmpwlxtjbt4 If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

Comment: What is the version of your selenium? Try updating selenium.

Comment: Hi Syed, it is the latest version - 2.53.6

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it. Firefox 48+ doesn't support `webdriver.Firefox()`.

My environment:
MacOS 10.11.6, python 3.5.2, firefox 48.0.2, Django 1.10, selenium 2.53.6

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
caps["marionette"] = True
caps["binary"] = "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin"

browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps)
browser.get('http://bbc.co.uk')
```

This is what I was trying
1. download `geckodriver`.https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases. `v.0.10.0`is for `selenium 3(beta)`. if you use `selenium 2.xx`, download `v.0.9.0`
2. open `~/.bash_profile`. you can edit it by `$ vim ~/.bash_profile`.
3. add PATH like..
`export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/your/.../geckodriver-v0.9.0-mac`
4. `geckodriver` under the folder `geckodriver-v0.9.0-mac`, rename it to  `wires`
5. restart shell
6. check the version
`$ wires --version`
7. and run above the code!

- [webdriver-mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver)